# How to join two table in mongodb with aggregate and lookup I have as array in second table?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections:

clients

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d203145b7b6c19b00ba576"),
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-22T15:06:21.564Z"),
    "status" : "live",
    "customerGUID" : "C8B910A3F74E",
    "apps" : [ 
        {
            "url" : "https://test.com",
            "loginGUID" : "12324654",
            "loginAPIAccessKey" : "B072-266C369743CA",
        }
    ],
    "avatar" : "",
    "description" : "",
    "firstName" : "firstname",
    "lastName" : "lastname",
    "email" : "company@test.com",
    "companyName" : "Company name",
}
```

visitors

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60aed4e0d6e30865f060be3c"),
    "lastName" : "CAIN",
    "firstName" : "DAVID",
    "loginAPIAccessKey" : "B072-266C369743CA",
    "email" : "cainins@att.net",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-26T23:08:16.505Z"),
    "activity" : []
}
```

I want all visitors which have active clients with `isDeleted: false` status. and the relationship between visitors and clients is `visitors.loginAPIAccessKey` and `clients.apps.loginAPIAccessKey` which is in an array of objects.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of the `$lookup` stage with the `pipeline` option.

```
db.visitors.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "clients",
      "let": {
        "loginAPIAccessKey": "$loginAPIAccessKey"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$apps"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$apps.loginAPIAccessKey",
                "$$loginAPIAccessKey"
              ],
            },
            "isDeleted": false,
          },
        },
      ],
      "as": "matchedClients"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "matchedClients": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    },
  },
])
```